# Sync data for offline usage with Wordpress and Ionic

Tags: wordpress, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build and app that sync the posts from wordpress ( data is highly dynamic and can cross 100-500 mb ) to ionic app which uses sqlite. At the same time download all assets to local. I developed an working code that does this. But I have problems to keep things in sync like check for changed posts, assets, etc. Also I have problem to keep track of deleted posts and stuff.

I am looking for alternates say like a library or some other alternate concepts that can help me keep that data in sync add, delete, update as it happens in server (need not be realtime).

Please do provide me some suggestions or ideas that I can try

Comment: [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/)+[pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) via [pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite)

Comment: @DaveAlden will give it a try. Thanks